# error type mismatch asynctask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to retrieve data from mysql using asynctask. But I got this

" Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask 
     to String"

Though the return from the asynctask process is already string

Here's my codes

```
     public void tampilkanPenyakit() {
                try {
                    String nama = URLEncoder.encode(username, "utf-8");
                    urltampil += "?" + "&nama=" + nama;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                xResult = getRequestTampil(urltampil);
                try {
                    parse();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    class ProsesTampil extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                     String sret = "";
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                    try{
                  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                      sret = EditPenyakit.request(response);

                    }catch(Exception ex){
                }

                    return sret;
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                }

            } 

     public String getRequestTampil(String UrlTampil){

              String sret="";
              sret= new ProsesTampil().execute(UrlTampil);

                return sret;

        }

private void parse() throws Exception {
                //jObject = new JSONObject(xResult);

               jObject = new JSONObject(xResult);
               String sret = "";
                JSONArray menuitemArray = jObject.getJSONArray("food");
                cb_menu1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_menu1);
                cb_menu2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_menu2);
                cb_menu3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_menu3);

                for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++) {
                    sret =menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                    "penyakit").toString();
                    System.out.println(sret);

                    if (sret.equals("1")){
                        cb_menu1.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    else if (sret.equals("2")){
                        cb_menu2.setChecked(true);
                    }

                }
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AsyncTask execute() method return the **Asyntask itself**, you cannot convert it to String.

You need to handle the result in the **onPostExecute()** method.

Other option could be use the [AsynTask get method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) :

```
sret= new ProsesTampil().execute(UrlTampil).get();
```

Take in account the doc:
**Waits if necessary** for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.